# Изменить стиль родителя в CSS3

Tags: css3

Как изменить стиль родительского контейнера при фокусе текущего силами CSS?

Например, есть `<td>` внутри `<input>`.
При фокусе на `input` надо изменить цвет фона `td`.

Остальные варианты сведутся к написанию js, т.к. инпут добавляется по событию, а у `td` есть `padding`, от которого не хочется избавляться, так как это приведет еще к одному контейнеру.

Comment: Нет, но в зависимости от того, что конкретно требуется изменить, можно попытаться это сделать другими способами. Предлагаю уточнить вопрос.

Comment: уточнять не нужно, как сделать это на js я знаю

Comment: Я имел в виду, может удастся сделать без js другим способом.

Comment: @Qwertiy, есть <td> внутри <input>, при фокусе инпута надо изменить бэк-колор td, остальные варианты сведутся к написанию js, т.к. инпут добавляется по событию, а у td есть padding, от которого избавляться не хочу, так как это приведет еще к одному контейнеру

Comment: Готово :)​​​​​​​

Comment: @DmitryOnGamer лучше вносить важную информацию в сам вопрос, а не использовать комментарии.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> есть `<td>` внутри `<input>`, при фокусе инпута надо изменить бэк-колор `td`

А ещё, можно использовать такой костыль:

```css
html {
  background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, #877cff 0%, #ff4747 100%) no-repeat;
  min-height: 100%;
}

table, tr, td {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 1px solid;
}

td {
  padding: 1em;
  overflow: hidden;
}

td, input {
  background: transparent;
}

input {
  border: 1px solid silver;
}

input:focus {
  background: yellow;
  outline: 9999px solid yellow;
  outline-offset: 0;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr><td><input><td><input><td><input></tr>
  <tr><td><input><td><input><td><input></tr>
  <tr><td><input><td><input><td><input></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: А ведь вариант со спаном лучше...

Answer (score 8):

CSS не позволяет обращаться к родительскому элементу. Для этого можно использовать JavaScript или jQuery (parentNode или parent() соответственно).

Answer (score 0):

> есть `<td>` внутри `<input>`, при фокусе инпута надо изменить бэк-колор `td`

Если `position` не мешает, то можно так:

```css
html {
  background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, #877cff 0%, #ff4747 100%) no-repeat;
  min-height: 100%;
}

table, tr, td {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 1px solid;
}

td {
  padding: 1em;
  position: relative;
}

td, input, span {
  background: transparent;
}

input {
  border: 1px solid silver;
}

span {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}

input:focus + span {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr><td><input><span></span><td><input><span></span><td><input><span></span></tr>
  <tr><td><input><span></span><td><input><span></span><td><input><span></span></tr>
  <tr><td><input><span></span><td><input><span></span><td><input><span></span></tr>
</table>
```